# LINQ: How to select elements of an array which have multiple properties with given values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a custom array

```
MyTypeA[] mA
```

`MyTypeA` contains properties including both `MyTypeB` and `MyTypeC` (named `mB` and `mC` for simplicity here)

I would like to select only those elements of `mA` such that `mB` has value `B` and `mC` has value `C`.

I tried something like:

```
mA.Select( x=>x.myB.Equals(B) && x=>x.myC.Equals(C)).ToList();
```

or also `Where()` but no progress.

I then want to use the result from this as an argument (arg) in

```
foreach (MyTypeD oneD in mD) oneD.AddTo(arg);
```

where mD is an array `MyTypeD[]`

where `AddTo()` has been declared as a method for MyTypeD:

```
public void AddTo(List<MyTypeA> mAin)
{
      mAin.CopyTo(AA);
}
```

Here `AA` is a property with the class `MyTypeD` of type `MyTypeA`

I have an error that the output of the query is of type `MyTypeD` and not a `List<MyTypeA>`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter you have to use `Where` of course but without multiple `x=>`:

```
var aQuery = mA.Where(a => a.myB.Equals(B) && a.myC.Equals(C));
```

For the sake of completeness, you can use multiple `Where` too:

```
var aQuery = mA.Where(a => a.myB.Equals(B)).Where(a => a.myC.Equals(C));
```

Comment: OK I tried that but then I have another problem...going to edit the question

Comment: Instead of the foreach use oneD.AddTo(mD.ToList());

Comment: Isn't the oneD defined in the foreach scope though?

Comment: True, since the method takes a list you have to append ToList(); to my query above. Then you can use your foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
mA.Where( x=>x.myB.Equals(B) && x.myC.Equals(C)).ToList();
```

Comment: OK I tried that but then I have another problem...going to edit the question